# Install ubuntu in Vmware 7.0

Tags: vmware

I wanna install ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso in Vmware 7.o X86 in Win7 64bit but after added in Vwmware a black page with a dash appear what can I do?
I try repeat it with ubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.iso after I select language and after that install ubuntu this error appear

Error 8000 reading sector 761961
Invalid or corrupt kernel Image

Plz help me soon
Tnx

Comment: Can you please include screenshots of the screen showing error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you see VMware Player should now work under Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu.html